# what is the role of debug in servlet configuration?

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets

I am working on a Spring application where in the web.xml I see a configuration.

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>debug</param-name>
            <param-value>0</param-value>
        </init-param>
</servlet>
```

Can anyone please tell me what is the meaning of debug here? I checked online but couldn't find a satisfactory solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The debug parameter configures the debug level of this servlet. The configuration is independent for each other servlet and very useful if you want more verbose output only for a single servlet.

Increase this value to get more verbose messages.

Comment: Will I get the more verbose messages in the server console, if the servlet throws an exception??

Comment: Yes, but I'm not really sure, on which debug level exactly the logging system considers exceptions. [link](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/default-servlet.html) says that valid values are between 0 and 100.

Comment: Thanks for the reply shylynx; Your answer is much appreciated :)